# Scala Neo4j OGM - Will not scan annotated NodeEntity classes - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: scala, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

**Problem:** Annotated classes are not being loaded into the class map.

My understanding on how to use the OGM:

- Pass your domain (which includes your `NodeEntity` annotated classes) to the `SessionFactory`
- Open a `Session`. At this point, behind the scenes, a class map of the annotated `NodeEntity` classes is built. This is referenced in the stacktrace on line 3 as "Building annotation class map". You'll see **it mapped 0** on the next line.
- Pass an instance of an annotated NodeEntity class to `session.save`
- Your entity is now saved in Neo4j!

In [this sample project](https://github.com/skyferthesly/Neo4jOgmEntityMappingExample), the domain is `testdomain`, and the only annotated `NodeEntity`, `Person`, is defined in the same file. I would expect this would eliminate any issues finding what classes to build into the persistent class map behind the scenes. But as seen in the log, the class map is not considering the domain I pass to `SessionFactory`.

**This prevents any data from being saved to Neo.**

You can clone the project and run the app yourself to reproduce the problem (instructions in README).

Stacktrace:

```
[info] Running testdomain.Test
2018-03-08 13:54:09 INFO  DomainInfo:160 - Starting Post-processing phase
2018-03-08 13:54:09 INFO  DomainInfo:126 - Building annotation class map
2018-03-08 13:54:09 INFO  DomainInfo:139 - Building interface class map for 0 classes
2018-03-08 13:54:09 INFO  DomainInfo:215 - Post-processing complete
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class class testdomain.Person is not a valid entity class. Please check the entity mapping.
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class class testdomain.Person is not a valid entity class. Please check the entity mapping.
[error]         at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:88)
[error]         at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:40)
[error]         at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:469)
[error]         at testdomain.Test$.delayedEndpoint$testdomain$Test$1(Test.scala:32)
[error]         at testdomain.Test$delayedInit$body.apply(Test.scala:26)
[error]         at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
[error]         at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
[error]         at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
[error]         at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
[error]         at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
[error]         at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
[error]         at testdomain.Test$.main(Test.scala:26)
[error]         at testdomain.Test.main(Test.scala)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:93)
[error]         at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:87)
[error]         at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:65)
[error]         at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:77)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]         at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
[error]         at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:252)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
[error]         at sbt.Run$.executeTrapExit(Run.scala:124)
[error]         at sbt.Run.run(Run.scala:77)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5(Defaults.scala:1169)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5$adapted(Defaults.scala:1164)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool.$anonfun$run$1(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:366)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]         at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.run(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:289)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed Mar 8, 2018 1:54:09 PM
```

I have searched high and low to try to resolve this issue. However, I am new at scala, so this must be something simple I am missing, right?

-skyfer

Comment: It seems that the problem is based in the usage of the `App` trait and might be caused by Scala's class loading behaviour.

Comment: As noted on the [Neo4j OGM Issues page](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/474), I've [attempted](https://github.com/skyferthesly/Neo4jOgmEntityMappingExample/tree/working_example) to forego using `App`, and was unsuccessful on getting a different result.

Comment: In an older version of Neo4j OGM, in [this](https://github.com/pram/ogm-example) project, annotated NodeEntity classes are loaded successfully:

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved with a modification to the `Neo4j OGM` library. The details are in [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/474) on their github.